# setRowHeight (specific) in google sheet app script

Tags: loops

I would like to batch resize (21 pixels) to all my sheets.
My code currently doesn't do anything and I can't find my error.
Do you have any clue?

```
function RowHeightSettings3() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
    var rowHeight = 21;

    // iterate through all the sheets from the first one in the spreadsheet
    for (var sheetNumber = 0; sheetNumber < allSheets.length; sheetNumber++) {

      s = allSheets[sheetNumber];

      // iterate through the rows
      for (var rowNumber = 1; rowNumber <= s.getLastRow();rowNumber++) {
        // set the row height on the current sheet to the desired height
        s.setRowHeight(rowNumber, rowHeight);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your question probably won't get many views unless you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61279804/edit) it to add tags for the relevant language and technology.

Comment: Thank you David for the cleanup.
Well my script works. I have launched it with 121 pixels height; all raws got adjusted.
Obviously, "setRowHeight" is overridden by text height.